# Сортировка по количеству вхождений

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

```
SELECT *, count(`title_prev` LIKE '%{$text}%') AS sort FROM `news` where `title_prev` LIKE '%{$text}%' ORDER BY sort limit 5
```

Попытался отсортировать записи по количеству вхождений, что та на выходе выдает одну запись вместо пяти

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `COUNT()` не считает количество "`вхождений`". он считает количество строк...в данном случае количество строк в котором поле `title_prev` содержит `%{$text}%`...и да: количество строк в таблице - это одно значение

Comment: также не совсем понимаю как приведенный SQL вообще выполнился. он должен был выдать ошибку по идее... ибо COUNT - это агрегатная функция и выбирать `*` вместе с количеством вы никак не могли

Comment: Как же сделать, как подсчитать количество вхождений по каждой строчке?

Comment: времени особо нет разбирать, но посмотрите это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427467/mysql-count-instances-of-substring-then-order-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменил функцию на поиск по нескольким ключам.

```
USE Test;

/* DROP FUNCTION fn_SubStringCount; */

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION fn_SubStringCount(AFullString VARCHAR(1000), ASubString VARCHAR(255), ADilimiter VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE InCount INT;    
    DECLARE aPos INT;
    DECLARE aPosKey INT;
    DECLARE aKey VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE isExit BIT;
    
    SET isExit = 0;
    SET InCount = 0;
    
    SET aPosKey = LOCATE(ADilimiter, ASubString, 1); 
    SET aKey = CASE WHEN aPosKey > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(ASubString, 1, aPosKey - 1) ELSE ASubString END;
    SET isExit = CASE WHEN aPosKey = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
    SET ASubString = SUBSTRING(ASubString, aPosKey + 1, LENGTH(ASubString) - aPosKey);
    
    label1: WHILE aKey IS NOT NULL DO       
        
        SET aPos = LOCATE(aKey, AFullString, 1);
        
        label2: WHILE aPos > 0 DO
            SET InCount = InCount + 1;
            SET aPos = LOCATE(aKey, AFullString, aPos + 1);     
        END WHILE label2;
        
        IF isExit = 1 THEN LEAVE label1; END IF;
                    
        SET aPosKey = LOCATE(ADilimiter, ASubString, 1); 
        SET aKey = CASE WHEN aPosKey > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(ASubString, 1, aPosKey - 1) ELSE ASubString END;
        SET isExit = CASE WHEN aPosKey = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
        SET ASubString = SUBSTRING(ASubString, aPosKey + 1, LENGTH(ASubString) - aPosKey);        
                        
    END WHILE label1;

    RETURN InCount;
END;
```

Пример использования тоже поменял:

```
USE Test;

CREATE TABLE TextStrings (Str VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT TextStrings (Str) VALUES ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, TEST1 consectetur adipiscing elit,');
INSERT TextStrings (Str) VALUES ('sed do eiusmod TeST1 tempor incididunt ut labore TEST2 et dolore magna aliqua.');
INSERT TextStrings (Str) VALUES ('Ut enim ad TEST3 minim veniam,');
INSERT TextStrings (Str) VALUES ('quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.');
INSERT TextStrings (Str) VALUES ('Duis aute irure TEST1 dolor in reprehenderit TEST3 in voluptate velit esse TEST2 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla TEST pariatur.');
INSERT TextStrings (Str) VALUES ('Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, TEST1 sunt in culpa qui TEST2 TEST2 TEST3 officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.');

SELECT fn_SubStringCount(ts.Str, 'TEST1|TEST2|TEST3', '|') FROM TextStrings ts;

DROP TABLE TextStrings;
```

Comment: Будет ли подсчет сразу по нескольким ключам. К примеру если написать так 'TEST|Имя'  и будет ли она без учета регистра, не учитывая регистр. Не разу не писал функции, попытаю добавить ее

Comment: В данной функции используется встроенная функция substring, а она регистронезависимая, значит и результат нашей функции будет регистронезависиым. Если нужно, могу модифицировать её для поиска по нескольким ключам. Это не сложно.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не substring, а locate =)

Comment: Был признательным, не разу ранее не писал функции под mysql. Чувствую просижу над этим...

Comment: Сделал, проверьте

Comment: Здорово, работает.

Comment: Возможно выполнить так, чтобы стало возможным указывать несколько полей? Или только по отдельности, а затем сумировать?

Comment: Можно передать в первый параметр сумму полей.  Например SELECT fn_SubStringCount(ts.Str1 + ts.Str2 + ts.Str3, 'TEST1|TEST2|TEST3', '|') FROM TextStrings ts. Это по сути будет то что вы и хотите.

Comment: Возможно сделать так, чтобы подсчитало не количество вхождений. А количество найденных ключей, и вернуть всю длину найденных найденных ключей. Допустим нашли ключ 'привет' и 'hello'. Вернуть не два, а 11. То есть длина двух найденных ключей = 11

Comment: Вторые сутки просидел пытаясь разобрать как это работает...

Comment: Напишите пример строки, которую нужно обработать, и пример результата. Я постараюсь вам помочь.

Comment: Ой, проглядел. Сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Решил добавить ещё один ответ.

Для подсчёта длины ключей модифицируем предыдущую функцию:

```
USE Test;

/* DROP FUNCTION fn_SubStringKeyLen; */

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION fn_SubStringKeyLen(AFullString VARCHAR(1000), ASubString VARCHAR(255), ADilimiter VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE keyLen INT;    
    DECLARE aPos INT;
    DECLARE aPosKey INT;
    DECLARE aKey VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE isExit BIT;
    
    SET isExit = 0;
    SET keyLen = 0;
    
    SET aPosKey = LOCATE(ADilimiter, ASubString, 1); 
    SET aKey = CASE WHEN aPosKey > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(ASubString, 1, aPosKey - 1) ELSE ASubString END;
    SET isExit = CASE WHEN aPosKey = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
    SET ASubString = SUBSTRING(ASubString, aPosKey + 1, LENGTH(ASubString) - aPosKey);
    
    label1: WHILE aKey IS NOT NULL DO       
        
        SET aPos = LOCATE(aKey, AFullString, 1);
        
        label2: WHILE aPos > 0 DO
            SET keyLen = keyLen + LENGTH(aKey);
            SET aPos = LOCATE(aKey, AFullString, aPos + 1);     
        END WHILE label2;
        
        IF isExit = 1 THEN LEAVE label1; END IF;
        
        
        SET aPosKey = LOCATE(ADilimiter, ASubString, 1); 
        SET aKey = CASE WHEN aPosKey > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(ASubString, 1, aPosKey - 1) ELSE ASubString END;
        SET isExit = CASE WHEN aPosKey = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
        SET ASubString = SUBSTRING(ASubString, aPosKey + 1, LENGTH(ASubString) - aPosKey);        
            
        
    END WHILE label1;

    RETURN keyLen;
END;
```

И соответственно пример:

```
USE Test;

CREATE TABLE TextStrings (Str VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT TextStrings (Str) VALUES ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, TEST1 consectetur adipiscing elit,');
INSERT TextStrings (Str) VALUES ('sed do eiusmod TeST1 tempor incididunt ut labore TEST2 et dolore magna aliqua.');
INSERT TextStrings (Str) VALUES ('Ut enim ad TEST3 minim veniam,');
INSERT TextStrings (Str) VALUES ('quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.');
INSERT TextStrings (Str) VALUES ('Duis aute irure TEST1 dolor in reprehenderit TEST3 in voluptate velit esse TEST2 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla TEST pariatur.');
INSERT TextStrings (Str) VALUES ('Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, TEST1 sunt in culpa qui TEST2 TEST2 TEST3 officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.');

SELECT fn_SubStringKeyLen(ts.Str, 'TEST1|TEST2|TEST3', '|') FROM TextStrings ts;

DROP TABLE TextStrings;
```

Comment: Здорово, возможно подсчитывать к примеру. Есть строчка "Текст текст", ищем по 'тe' находим, выводим не 4, а два. То есть найден один ключ, не важно сколько раз употребляется в тексте. Есть ключ  +1(длина ключа 2, то есть на выходе 2). Второй раз нет необходимости засчитывать тот же ключ. То есть считаем только уникальные вхождения, повторные исключаем.

Comment: Дело в том, что пользователь может намеренно добавить несколько одинаковых ключей чтобы в поиске выдало в первых позициях. Не совсем честно получается и интереса меньше к публикаям в которых больше спама... Я хорошо не разбираюсь в функциях по mysql, но если выполнить так то и нагрузка будет ниже на сервер.

Comment: Не знаю почему, но по нескольким полям у меня не ищет. Выдает просто 0

Comment: Я подготовил ответ, в котором одинаковые ключи не учитываются в поиске, и ключи проверяются на уникальность... 3-й ответ писать?)

Comment: Все работает, спс

Comment: Ну классно) пишите если что

Answer (score 1):

Без комментариев.

```
USE Test;

DROP FUNCTION fn_SubStringKeyLenUnique;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION fn_SubStringKeyLenUnique(AFullString VARCHAR(1000), ASubString VARCHAR(255), ADilimiter VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE keyLen INT;    
    DECLARE aPos INT;
    DECLARE aPosKey INT;
    DECLARE aKey VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE isExit BIT;
    
    SET NAMES utf8;
    
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tKeys  (vKey VARCHAR(255));
    
    SET isExit = 0;
    SET keyLen = 0;
    
    SET aPosKey = LOCATE(ADilimiter, ASubString, 1); 
    SET aKey = CASE WHEN aPosKey > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(ASubString, 1, aPosKey - 1) ELSE ASubString END;
    SET isExit = CASE WHEN aPosKey = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
    SET ASubString = SUBSTRING(ASubString, aPosKey + 1, CHARACTER_LENGTH(ASubString) - aPosKey);
    
    label1: WHILE aKey IS NOT NULL DO       
        
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tKeys WHERE vKey = aKey) THEN
            SET aPos = LOCATE(aKey, AFullString, 1);
            IF aPos > 0 THEN SET keyLen = keyLen + CHARACTER_LENGTH(aKey); END IF;
            INSERT INTO tKeys (vKey) VALUES (aKey);
        END IF;
            
        IF isExit = 1 THEN LEAVE label1; END IF;
        
        SET aPosKey = LOCATE(ADilimiter, ASubString, 1); 
        SET aKey = CASE WHEN aPosKey > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(ASubString, 1, aPosKey - 1) ELSE ASubString END;
        SET isExit = CASE WHEN aPosKey = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
        SET ASubString = SUBSTRING(ASubString, aPosKey + 1, CHARACTER_LENGTH(ASubString) - aPosKey);        
            
    END WHILE label1;
    
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tKeys;
    
    RETURN keyLen;
END;
```

Comment: Поиск по одинаковым ключам повторяться не будет. Несколько раз один и тот же ключ не будет искаться в строке.

Comment: Если поле содержит англ содержимое, работает верно, ошибок нету. А вот если поле содержит к примеру 'О современной науке' и ищем к примеру 'M' либо 'п', что та одно, результат будет равен 2. А если искать 'М|п' результат равен 4. Не знаю, количество 'н' в тексте 3, 'м' = 1. Вроде бы и работает, но что та не так. Добавил скриншоты в вопрос

Comment: Я ещё раз проверил всё, включая кириллицу, всё работает как нужно. Но, я заметил что во всех ваших скринах используется одно и то же название функции, а я, обратите внимание, во всех ответах давал новое имя функции, проверьте, может где то путаница вышла.

Comment: Всё, я разобрался с вашей проблемой. Это связано с UTF8, для русских символов возвращается не по 1 байту а по 2, отсюда результат такой. Заменил на другую функцию, проверьте.